# Select/Move/Copy image files with a specific name in its filename using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to move certain image files with a specific name in its filename.

The filename is as follows:

```
filename 1 = This_is_a_BAD_image.jpg
filename 2 = This_is_a_GOOD_image.jpg
```

The filenames are separated by underscores. I want to specifically cut and paste or "move" the images with "GOOD" in its filename (basically filename 2) to another folder. And then I want to just copy and paste the images with "BAD" in its filename. I tried using startswith() variable but since the text that I want is not in the first part, it doesn't work.

I haven't tried anything yet since my google search came out empty. Appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

how about using `shutil` module to copy and move files, if `GOOD` is find in the filename then move, if 'BAD' found in the filename, copy it :

```
source_folder = '/path/to/source/folder'
destination_folder = '/path/to/destination/folder'

for filename in os.listdir(source_folder):
    if 'GOOD' in filename:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_folder, filename), os.path.join(destination_folder, filename))
    elif 'BAD' in filename:
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(source_folder, filename), os.path.join(destination_folder, filename))
```

Comment: One possible caveat here is if you want to match on GOOD but not FEELGOOD or GOODNESS.  It may be necessary to use the `re` module to specifically check for "_GOOD_", while also account for cases where the target word is the first  or last piece of the filename.

Comment: It would be more accurate to test as follows `if '_GOOD_' in filename` and likewise `_BAD_`